# How do I find an AjaxToolkit TabContainer in the code behind?

Tags: asp.net

I have a tabcontainer in a repeater. When the page builds I want to set the active tab. How do I find it in the code behind?

This doesn't work:

```
AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer tc = FindControl("projTabContainer");
```

because I'm trying to cast a control to a tabcontainer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `TabContainer` is in an `ItemTemplate` of a `Repeater`, you have to set the `ActiveTab` in [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx). That's also the only place where you can find it in this way since the `RepeaterItem` is it's `NamingContainer`.

```
void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
{
     if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
     {
         var tc = (AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer)e.Item.FindControl("projTabContainer");
         tc.ActiveTab = ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer tc = e.Item.FindControl("projTabContainer") as AjaxControlToolkit.TabContainer;
```